# Remove spacing between spans using css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

For some reason I can't seem to get rid of the vertical spacing between these two spans, I know I'm missing something simple but any help would be appreciated.

The issue I'm having is the significant vertical space showing between these two spans:

```
<span class="twentyeight nomargin threshold_green">6</span>
<br style="display:none;">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<span class="zeroeight nomargin threshold_green">(04:32)</span>
```

Complete code is on fiddle, it was just cleaner than trying to post it here. http://jsfiddle.net/ehn7dzxc/2/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] *in your question*.

Comment: So how do you want it to look? Do you want the text to be *flush* up against one another? As in, in the same cell?

Comment: remove `<br>`  just add `<p>` before `<span>`  or use your class to it up or down

Answer (score 0):

```js
 window.onload = function(){
       var cells = ["1_1_H","1_1_B","1_1_F","1_2_H","1_2_B","1_2_F","1_3_H","1_3_B","1_3_F","2_1_H","2_1_B","2_1_F","2_2_H","2_2_B","2_2_F","2_3_H","2_3_B","2_3_F"];
       get_cellHF(cells,"CCC_CCT_VOICE"); 

      };
```

```css
html, body, .outer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
div.outer {
  display: table;
}
table.actionBoard {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table.actionBoard td, table.actionBoard th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.actionBoard tbody td {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
table.actionBoard tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
div.cell_container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
div.cell_block {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: table;
}
div.cell_body {
 font-size: 72px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: relative;
 height: 95%;
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 top: -10%;
}
div.cell_header {
 font-size: 2.5vh;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: relative;
 height: 5%;
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-row;
 top: 0px;
}
div.cell_footer {
 font-size: 2vh;
 font-family: "Arial", Gadget, sans-serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: relative;
 height: 5%;
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-row;
 top: 5%;
}
.threshold_green {
 color: #00FF00;
}
.threshold_orange {
 color: #FF8800;
}
.threshold_red {
 color: #FF0000;
}
.threshold_white {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.threehundred {
 font-size: 35vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 35vmin;
}
.thirtyfive {
 font-size: 35vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 35vmin;
}
.thirtyzero {
 font-size: 29vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 30.5vmin;
}
.twentyeight {
 font-size: 26vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 27.5vmin;
}
.twentyfive {
 font-size: 18vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 19.5vmin;
}
.tenfive {
 font-size: 10vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 10vmin;
}
.zeroeight {
 font-size: 06vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 06vmin;
}
.nomargin {
 margin: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.aligntop {
 vertical-align: top;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css?time=6" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="outer">
      <table class="actionBoard">
       <tbody><tr>
           <td colspan="2" id="cell1_1">
            <div class="cell_container">
             <div class="cell_block">
              <div class="cell_header" id="cell1_1_H"></div>
              <div class="cell_footer" id="cell1_1_F"></div>
              <div class="cell_body" id="cell1_1_B"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </td>
           <td colspan="2" id="cell1_2">
            <div class="cell_container">
             <div class="cell_block">
              <div class="cell_header" id="cell1_2_H"></div>
              <div class="cell_footer" id="cell1_2_F"></div>
              <div class="cell_body" id="cell1_2_B">
 <a href="fake.html" target="_blank">
  <span style='display:block' class="twentyeight nomargin threshold_green">6</span>
  
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <span style='display:block' class="zeroeight nomargin threshold_green">(04:32)</span>
 </a>
</div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </td>
           <td colspan="2" id="cell1_3">
            <div class="cell_container">
             <div class="cell_block">
              <div class="cell_header" id="cell1_3_H"></div>
              <div class="cell_footer" id="cell1_3_F"></div>
              <div class="cell_body" id="cell1_3_B"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </td>
           </tr><tr>
           <td colspan="2" id="cell2_1">
            <div class="cell_container">
             <div class="cell_block">
              <div class="cell_header" id="cell2_1_H"></div>
              <div class="cell_footer" id="cell2_1_F"></div>
              <div class="cell_body" id="cell2_1_B"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </td>
           <td colspan="2" id="cell2_2">
            <div class="cell_container">
             <div class="cell_block">
              <div class="cell_header" id="cell2_2_H"></div>
              <div class="cell_footer" id="cell2_2_F"></div>
              <div class="cell_body" id="cell2_2_B"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </td>
           <td colspan="2" id="cell2_3">
            <div class="cell_container">
             <div class="cell_block">
              <div class="cell_header" id="cell2_3_H"></div>
              <div class="cell_footer" id="cell2_3_F"></div>
              <div class="cell_body" id="cell2_3_B"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </td>
           </tr></tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </body>
    
   </html>
```

Comment: What is all that? How does it answer the question? What does it do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Ok. What did you change? How and why does that fix the problem and answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Code only and throw an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: get_cellHF is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `display: block;` to your 2nd span there. Seems to have done the trick for me

So your `.zeroeight` class should look something like this

```
.zeroeight {
 font-size: 06vm; /* fallback for IE */
 font-size: 06vmin;
 display: block;
}
```

I assume this class is used elsewhere so you may want to find a better solution to apply this style to that bottom `span`

See http://jsfiddle.net/ehn7dzxc/13/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `<br>` and the `<div>` so that you just have the following:

```
<span class="twentyeight nomargin threshold_green">6</span>
<span class="zeroeight nomargin threshold_green">(04:32)</span>
```

That unwanted space you have is from the default `line-height: normal`. You can override this by applying the following to your CSS:

```
.nomargin {
  display: block; /* to honor the line break since we're removing the <br> and <div>
  line-height: 1; /* this is your spacing fix */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed. So without any change just add one CSS property in your code.

```
.nomargin {
   margin: 0px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   display: block;
}
```

Also, the complete code is on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ehn7dzxc/18/